# How does fromIntegral work?

Tags: haskell

The type of `fromIntegral` is `(Num b, Integral a) => a -> b`. I'd like to understand how that's possible, what the code is that can convert any Integral number to any number type as needed.

The [actual code](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Real.html#fromIntegral) for `fromIntegral` is listed as

```
fromIntegral = fromInteger . toInteger
```

The [code](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Num.html#fromInteger) for `fromInteger` is under `instance Num Int` and `instance Num Integer` They are respectively:

```
instance  Num Int  where
  ...
  fromInteger i = I# (integerToInt i)
```

and

```
instance  Num Integer  where
  ...
  fromInteger x  =  x
```

Assuming `I#` calls a C program that converts an `Integer` to an `Int` I don't see how either of these generate results that could be, say, added to a `Float`. How do they go from `Int` or `Integer` to something else?

`fromInteger` will be embedded in an expression which requires that it produce a certain type. It can't know what the required type will be? So what happens?

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because `fromInteger` is part of the `Num` class, every instance will have its own implementation. *Neither* of the two implementations (for `Int` and `Integer`) knows how to make a `Float`, but they aren't called when you're using `fromInteger` (or `fromIntegral`) to make a `Float`; that's what the `Float` instance of `Num` is for.

And so on for all other types. There is no one place that knows how to turn integers into any `Num` type; that would be impossible, since it would have to support user-defined `Num` instances that don't exist yet. Instead when each individual type is declared to be an instance of `Num` a way of doing that *for that particular type* must be provided (by implementing `fromInteger`).

> `fromInteger` will be embedded in an expression which requires that it produce a certain type. It can't know what the required type will be? So what happens?

Actually, knowing what type it's expected to return from the expression the call is embedded in is *exactly* how it works.

Type checking/inference in Haskell works in two "directions" at once. It goes top-down, figuring out what types each expression *should* have, in order to fit into the bigger expression it's being used in. And it also goes "bottom-up", figuring out what type each expression should have from the smaller sub-expressions it's built out of. When it finds a place where those don't match, you get a type error (that's exactly where the "expected type" and "actual type" you see in type error messages cone from).

But because the compiler has that top-down knowledge (the "expected type") for every expression, it's perfectly able to figure out that a call of `fromInteger` is being used where a `Float` is expected, and so use the `Float` instance for `Num` in that call.

Answer (score 5):

One aspect that distinguishes type classes from OOP interfaces is that type classes can dispatch on the *result* type of a method, not only on the type of its parameters. The classic example is the `read :: Read a => String -> a` function.

---

`fromInteger` has type `fromInteger :: Num a => Integer -> a`. The implementation is selected depending on the type of `a`. If the typechecker knows that `a` is a `Float`, the `Num` instance of `Float` will be used, not the one of `Int` or `Integer`.